# msyql ROUNDING for FLAT RATE charging

Tags: mysql

Need help with rounding values, I know `ROUND()` exists but it's not quite what I needed.

So, I'm calculating call rates per minute, in which in a flat rate basis, any call goes more than 60seconds will be charged for the next minute.

My query goes `SEC_TO_TIME`(billedsec) to get the minute equivalent.

I have 2 issues:

1. How to round off to a full minute for values that goes more than a minute say, if 1min and 15sec (`00:01:15`) should be 2mins or 13seconds must be a full minute.
2. How to calculate TIME format to an int or float to get the actual rate
   e.g `00:01:00*rate`? Is it straightfoward approach?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
FLOOR((billedsec+59)/60)
```

to get the time rounded up to the next minute. 13 seconds will go to 72/60=1 minute, 60 seconds will go to 119/60=1 minute, 61 seconds will go to 120/60=2 minutes, 75 seconds will go to 134/60=2 minutes etc.

Comment: THANK YOU! This did the job! OMG! you made my life much easier. UP UP UP!

Comment: No worries. Glad to be of help.

Comment: Or just `CEIL(billedsec/60)` @Nick?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, but... I've occasionally run into situations where limits to floating point precision mean something like 60/60 can be fractionally more than 1 and then `CEIL` rounds it up to 2. Using `FLOOR` like this is guaranteed safe.